# How do I get from google-services.json to GoogleServices-info.plist?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am building for iOS in Unity using the Firebase Unity plugin and getting an error that says that there is no GoogleServices-info.plist found in my project and so it fails to build for iOS. According to the Firebase docs, you're supposed to download the plist file from the Dasboard but of course when you go there you find they only offer you a .json file download for iOS projects.

What am I missing? How do I get a .plist file? Is it supposed to generate?

Comment: Try to follow this doc: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On firebase, if you create an iOS app for your project, the file it offers to download is actually a .plist file.

On the overview of your project it shows your app, you should have the android and the iOS one there:
[image]

Then you click on the options for your iOS app
[image]
Click on "Settings"

Then from here:
[image]
Click on "GoogleService-Info.plist"

Can you check your project has an iOS app?

Comment: Thanks -- that was it. As it turns out there are two very similar paths and one leads to a .json file (overall project settings) and the other one (specific app settings) leads to a .plist file. There is also an additional step where you have to actually add the .plist file to your Unity project. I put mine in a Plugins/iOS folder.

Comment: @screenglow Hi, I am developing a PC game with unity, and there is no option for PC, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

```
▪   Go to dashboard select your app  
▪    Go Settings > general > your apps 
▪    Select iOS app
▪   Click on Download the latest config file
```

You will get info.plist file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to download file GoogleServices-info.plist and google-service.json .

google-service.json file is used in android while GoogleServices-info.plist is used IOS.

For firebase setup in ionic you have to use both files. You have to setup a single project containing two apps android and ios as well.

- create project
- from the dashboard, add app android. Type android package name and name of the application then download google-service.json file in second setup.
- add app for ios, type IOS bundler id and name. Then download file GoogleServices-info.plist in second step.  Then, configure the project.